# Using pointers to replace values

Tags: c

This is my first task using pointers...
I'm need to create a function that finds out which of two numbers is bigger, and than replace both of them to have the bigger value and print them.

I'm getting an error in the `prinf` of the `main()` :

> argument type 'void' is incomplete

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void larger_of(double * x, double * y);

int main()

{
    double num1 = 4.5;
    double num2 = 5.5;

    printf("the original two numbers is %.1lf and %.1lf\n", num1, num2);
    printf("now: %lf and %lf", larger_of(&num1, &num2));

}

void larger_of(double * x, double * y)

{
    if (* x > * y)
        * y = * x;
    else if
       (* x < * y)
        * x = * y;
    else
        printf("they are equale!!");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`larger_of` is a function that returns nothing. You cannot print its return value.

To print your numbers after a call to `larger_of` just do:

```
larger_of(&num1, &num2);
printf("now: %lf and %lf", num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to print the void

```
printf("now: %lf and %lf", larger_of(&num1, &num2));
```

what you have to do :

```
larger_of(&num1, &num2)
printf("now: %lf and %lf",num1,num2);
```